# How to Convert JSON Data into an Object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-4.0, .class-file

I have a JSON array like so:

```
theFormData = {"FormNodeID":142365,"SubmissionMethod":"Desktop","ConfirmationEmailID":"142371","FirstName":"Solomon","LastName":"Closson","EmailAddress":"myemail@testing.com","Company":"TIF","JobTitle":"Web Developer"}
```

`FormNodeID`, `SubmissionMethod`, and `ConfirmationEmailID` will always be the same, however, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `EmailAddress`, `Company`, and `JobTitle` are being populated into JSON with javascript as a string that will change according to the value that the Administrator has put into a Label, and uses a regex to remove the special chars and spaces.

So, I have code that populates this into another variable, called `theProperty` and than I add these JSON objects to it like so:

`theFormData[theProperty] = value;`

where value equals the inputs value.  The thing is, I need to be able to transfer this JSON variable into an ASP.NET C# Class File `.cs` and build the class properties dynamically from the JSON Objects.  Is this possible?

Right now am sending it to a Handler with the following code:

```
var formdata = 'formdata=' + encodeURIComponent(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(theFormData));
MakeRequest('/handlers/formshandler.ashx?f=formcontrol&r=' + Math.random(), 'POST', formdata, SaveComplete, null);
```

The MakeRequest and it's dependency Functions look like this:

```
function MakeRequest (url, verb, data, func, obj) {
    try {
        var TheRequest = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();

        TheRequest.set_url(url);
        TheRequest.set_httpVerb(verb);

        if (data) {
            TheRequest.set_body(data);
        }
        TheRequest.set_userContext(new RequestParamsNew(func, obj));
        TheRequest.add_completed(MakeRequestComplete);
        TheRequest.invoke();

        return TheRequest;
    }
    catch (error) {
        if (func) func('Communication Error');
    }
}
function MakeRequestComplete (executer, eventArgs) 
{
    var TheParams = executer.get_webRequest().get_userContext();

    if (executer.get_responseAvailable()) 
    {
        TheParams.responseData = executer.get_responseData().replace(/\u2028/g, '');
    }
    else 
    {
        TheParams.responseData = null;
    }
    if (TheParams.func) TheParams.func(TheParams);
}

function RequestParamsNew(afunc, obj) 
{
    this.func         = afunc;
    this.responseData = null;
    this.obj          = obj;
    this.Error        = null;
}
```

This passes it to a Form Handler located in handlers/formhandler.ashx

In this file, I check the request of f and than grab the posted `formdata` like so:

```
CustomForm theCustomForm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CustomForm>(_Context.Request["formdata"]);
```

So CustomForm is a Class file that I need to be able to populate the properties exactly from that of the formdata JSON variable.  This doesn't seem to do this.  It seems to be able to get the values, but I have to have the public properties set within the `CustomForm.cs` file  Manually inputted in the .cs file.  But instead, I need it to create the properties based on the JSON automatically, because the properties will most likely be different for different forms.

How is this possible to do?

***EDIT***

Ok, so now using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of a class as per comments on this.

In the handler, now using this code:

```
List<string> theErrors = new List<string>();

Dictionary<string, string> theCustomForm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(_Context.Request["‌​formdata"]);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in theCustomForm)
{
    theErrors.Add(pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value);
}

_Context.Response.Write(new
{
    Valid = theErrors.Count == 0,
    Errors = theErrors,
    Message = "Form Submitted"
}.ToJson());
```

Just testing to see if any `Errors` are returned at all.  My SaveComplete function looks like this:

```
function SaveComplete(params) {
    if (params.responseData) {
        var theItems = eval(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(params.responseData, false));

        if (theItems.Valid) {
           // Redirect somewhere...
           document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        else {
            $.each(theItems.Errors, function (idx, error) {
                Console.Log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following Error:

```
Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data
```

If I change `theItems` part in the `SaveComplete` function to this:

```
var theItems = params.responseData;
alert(theItems);
```

It alerts the following (a 500 Page Error):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <title>PHL</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/media/1606636/homestead_favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jquery-select2/select2.css" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/datepicker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/qrs7pfm.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">      try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/BaseUI.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="var-nav" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div id="Container" class="secondary">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header-elements clearfix">
      <div class="header-row row">
        <header class="header container">
          <div class="main-nav nav-small">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav-buttons">
                  <li class="phl-logo"><a href="/">PHL</a></li>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>      
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div id="call-phl">1-800-CALL-PHL</div>
    </div>
    <!-- .Header -->


    <div id="hero-slideshow" class="hero-slideshow">
      <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="/images/SAMPLE_slide-grad-bg.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page tertiary bg_pattern">
      <div class="">
        <div class="row-inner breadcrumbs-row">
            <ul class="breadcrumbs clearfix">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li>Error 500</li>
          </ul>        
        </div>          
        <div class="row-inner bg_pattern">
            <h1>Error 500: Internal Server Error</h1>
            <!-- Right Rail Column -->
            <div class="right-rail clearfix">
            <div class="body article-body">            
                <div class="article container">                
                <p>The server was unable to send the html document to you due to an internal (server software) error.</p>
                <p>If the issue persists, contact <a href="#">webmaster@discoverPHL.com</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rail">
            </div>
          </div>
            <!-- Right Rail Column -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- .Footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is coming from 500.htm file within the website root.  Is there something in the web.config file that needs to be done for this that I'm missing perhaps?

`Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(theFormData)` returns the JSON just fine, so it must be in the way it is being deserialized perhaps?

Comment: try `Dictionary<string,string> theCustomForm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(_Context.Request["formdata"]);`

Comment: Awesome, that seems to resolve with no errors!  Great!  Gonna try to work with the Dictionary instead of a Class file.  Looks promising! Never worked with a Dictionary before... Just need to figure out how to get the values of the Dictionary now.  Cheers :)

Comment: Well, using Dictionary, I can't seem to get the responseData I need from the handler within the javascript...  I will edit my question with the new code I'm using, maybe someone can help, cause it comes back as undefined in the jQuery `$.each` function.

Comment: Ok, seems there was a catch on this that I overlooked, and removed it, and now gives me this:  `Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data`

Comment: possibly `params.responseData` already js object.

Comment: @Grundy - If I alert `params.responseData` as is, I get html data for a 500 page error.... this is crazy!  Not sure what is causing this, but looks like custom coding causing it.

Comment: Why not use http://json.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: @Pier - I copied over the dll from the Bin Directory, I suppose that's how you install it, Rebuilt the Website, now it still says, that JsonConvert is undefined, not sure how to use this...

Comment: Seems like the problem is here:  `Dictionary<string, string> theCustomForm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(_Context.Request["‌​formdata"]);`  Shouldn't it be an `object` of some sort??

Comment: can you provide value of `Context.Request["‌​formdata"]`? and also what error you get?

Comment: `_Context.Request["‌​formdata"]` = `{"FormNodeID":142365,"SubmissionMethod":"Desktop","ConfirmationEmailID":"142371","FirstName":"Solomon","LastName":"Closson","Email":"solomon_closson@email.com","Company":"My Company","JobTitle":"My Job Title"}`  So this is returning JSON already without deserializing it, but how to convert it to ASP.NET to do things with it?  The Dictionary code your provided doesn't evaluate it properly... gives error when Deserializing I suppose.  I just need to convert this to ASP somehow to use...

Comment: Here is the error I get with the `Dictionary`:  `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: input at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)     at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)`

Comment: `at MMG.PresentationLayer.Handlers.FormsHandler.SubmitCustomForm() in FormsHandler.cs:line 127     at MMG.PresentationLayer.Handlers.FormsHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext aContext) in FormsHandler.cs:line 33     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)`

Comment: FormsHandler.cs:line 127 = `Dictionary<string, string> theCustomForm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(_Context.Request["‌​formdata"]);`

Comment: I think it needs to be an `Object` of some sort, but don't know how to get it into an object and than be able to loop through it and find out it's parts...

Comment: This seems to work without errors:  `Object theCustomForm = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Object>(_Context.Request["formdata"]);`, however, don't know how to loop through it to get the Json of the object, or perhaps I can transfer the object to a Dictionary somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is resolved with the following:

```
public void SubmitCustomForm()
{
    List<string> theErrors = new List<string>();

    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(_Context.Request["formdata"]);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
    {
        theErrors.Add(pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value);
    }

    _Context.Response.Write(new
    {
        Valid = theErrors.Count == 0,
        Errors = theErrors,
        Message = "Form Submitted"
    }.ToJson());            
}
```

This validates perfectly fine with no errors.  Not sure why the other approach didn't work, but this atleast works perfect now and lets me handle the Dictionary items...